# Repeated column in mapping for entity should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I am having a pojo class Address and I am trying build a database table where there should be different home address and office address. I am using AttributeOverride annotation to get make the address class to show property of office address and home address seperately, however I am getting the below issue. 
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.blogPost.Employee column: CITY_NAME (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Please see the below code and suggest the corrrect fix for this.

Main Class.

```
    package org.blogPost;
    import java.util.Date;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

    public class TestEmployee {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SessionFactory sessionfactory = new 
            AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Date date= new Date();
            Employee emp1= new Employee();
            Address addr= new Address();
            Address home_addr= new Address();
            addr.setStreet("This is a test street");
            addr.setCity("test city");
            addr.setPincode("test Pin");
            home_addr.setStreet("Home Street Test");
            home_addr.setCity("Home test home");
            home_addr.setPincode("Test_home pin");
            //emp1.setEmpId(101);
            emp1.setEmpName("Employee five");
            emp1.setEmpLastName("Employee five SirName");
            emp1.setNumber(7755);
            emp1.setEmail("emp55@hibernate.com");
            emp1.setAddress(home_addr);
            emp1.setOfficeAddress(addr);
            emp1.setEmpLoginTime(date);
            session.save(emp1);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            emp1= null;

            session=sessionfactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            emp1=(Employee)session.get(Employee.class, 1);
            System.out.println("Below is the user details");
            System.out.println("Employee ID : "+emp1.getEmpId());
            System.out.println("Employee Name : "+emp1.getEmpName());
            System.out.println("Employee Address : "+emp1.getAddress());
            System.out.println("Employee email ID : "+emp1.getEmail());

        }
    }
```

Employee Class where I am facing the issue.

> > ```
> > package org.blogPost;
> >
> > import java.util.Date;
> >
> > import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
> > import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
> > import javax.persistence.Column;
> > import javax.persistence.Embedded;
> > import javax.persistence.Entity;
> > import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
> > import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
> > import javax.persistence.Id;
> > import javax.persistence.Table;
> > import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
> > import javax.persistence.Temporal;
> > import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
> >
> > @Entity
> > @Table(name="EmployeeInfo")
> > public class Employee {
> >
> >     private int empId;
> >     private String empName;
> >     private String empLastName;
> >     private long number;
> >     private String email;
> >     private Date empLoginTime;
> >     private Address address;
> >
> >     @AttributeOverrides({
> >     @AttributeOverride 
> >     (name="street",column=@Column(name="HOME_STREET_ADDRESS")),
> >     @AttributeOverride 
> >     (name="city",column=@Column(name="HOME_CITY_ADDRESS")),
> >     @AttributeOverride 
> >         (name="pincode",column=@Column(name="HOME_PIN_CODE"))   
> >     })
> >     private Address officeAddress;
> >
> >     @Id
> >     @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE,generator="empID")
> >       @TableGenerator(name="empID",table="empPrimaryKey",pkColumnName="empKey",pkColumnValue="empValue",allocationSize=1)
> >     @Column(name="EmployeeId",nullable=false)
> >     public int getEmpId() {
> >         return empId;
> >     }
> >     public void setEmpId(int empId) {
> >         this.empId = empId;
> >     }
> >     @Column(name="First_Name",nullable=false)
> >     public String getEmpName() {
> >         return empName;
> >     }
> >     public void setEmpName(String empName) {
> >         this.empName = empName;
> >     }
> >     @Column(name="Last_Name",nullable=false)
> >     public String getEmpLastName() {
> >         return empLastName;
> >     }
> >     public void setEmpLastName(String empLastName) {
> >         this.empLastName = empLastName;
> >     }
> >     @Column(name="Phone_number")
> >     public long getNumber() {
> >         return number;
> >     }
> >     public void setNumber(long number) {
> >         this.number = number;
> >     }
> >     @Column(name="Email_Address",nullable=false)
> >     public String getEmail() {
> >         return email;
> >     }
> >     public void setEmail(String email) {
> >         this.email = email;
> >     }
> >     @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
> >     public Date getEmpLoginTime() {
> >         return empLoginTime;
> >     }
> >     public void setEmpLoginTime(Date empLoginTime) {
> >         this.empLoginTime = empLoginTime;
> >     }
> >     @Embedded
> >     public Address getAddress() {
> >         return address;
> >     }
> >     public void setAddress(Address address) {
> >         this.address = address;
> >     }
> >     @Embedded
> >     public Address getOfficeAddress() {
> >         return officeAddress;
> >     }
> >     public void setOfficeAddress(Address officeAddress) {
> >         this.officeAddress = officeAddress;
> >     }
> >
> >
> > }
> > ```

Address class.
    package org.blogPost;

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String pincode;

    @Column(name="STREET_NAME")
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }
    @Column(name="CITY_NAME")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    @Column(name="PIN_CODE")
    public String getPincode() {
        return pincode;
    }
    public void setPincode(String pincode) {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

}
```

Below is the exception I am getting when I run the code.

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.blogPost.Employee column: CITY_NAME (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:670)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:692)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:688)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:714)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:468)
>     at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:215)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1149)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1334)
>     at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
>     at org.blogPost.TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:12)
> ```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the `officeAddress`  and `address`, they are all `Address` class with annotation `@Embedded`.

Comment: You are correct , and that is the reason I am using AttributeOverride to overcome this confusion, however it is still giving me the exception

Answer (score 1):

Please keep  @AttributeOverrides annotation on getter method(public Address getOfficeAddress()) just like you have used annotations on getter methods of other member variables(public int getEmpId()). It will work.